# Xpath ancestor finding div

Tags: xpath

I got html looking like this

```
<div id="depositModalxx" class="modal hide">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3> Deposit </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

And in this file there is more than 1 modal, so i need to find it by text. I tried this

```
ancestor::div[.//div/h3/text() = 'Deposit']
```

But this returns more than just that div i am searching. Any ideas how to get just that div i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
//div[div/h3 = ' Deposit ']
```

If you also want to check that the div has the `modal` class you can do

```
//div[contains(@class, 'modal')][div/h3 = ' Deposit ']
```

I don't quite get why you don't simply search using the `@id`. As an id should be unique in the HTML anyways, you should also be able to select the element easily and realiably.

Comment: This is for selenium tests and @id is generating randomly by Wicket framework